# How to draw multiple returns in UML sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

In UML sequence diagram a method can have only one return line (at least in Astah I'm unable to draw two return lines from one method), how can I model multiple returns in if-else blocks?

In below example, return line 'a' ends methodX(), how to draw return line 'b'?

```
String methodX(int i) {
  if (i>0)
    return 'a';
  else
    return 'b';
}

     +------------+            +------------+
     |    Foo     |            |     Bar    |
     +-----+------+            +------+-----+
           |                          |
           |        methodX(i)         |
          +-+----------------------->+-+
          | |                        | |
  +-----+------------------------------------+
  | alt | | |  [i>0]                 | |     |
  +-----+ | |           a            | |     |
  |       | |<- - - - - - - - - - - -+-+     |
  |       | |                         |      |
  |       | |                         |      |
  +------------------------------------------+
  |       | |  [else]                 |      |
  |       | |                         |      |
  |       | |           b             |      |
  |       | |<- - - - - - - - - - - - | ??   |
  |       | |                         |      |
  |       | |                         |      |
  +------------------------------------------+
          | |                         |
          +-+                         |
           +                          +
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your tool, not with UML. Check out [visual paradigm for UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/). You can manually add activations at the start of each `alt` fragment and at the end of the activation send the return message.

Answer (score 1):

Quick observations:

(1) Remember, that a class / object may send messages to itself ( "DoSomething" ),
this makes "alternatives" more diificult to appreaciate.

(2) When using "alt", you have to mention conditions. "alt", represents "if-then-else", "switch-case", and similar concepts from programming languages.

And those sentences, have conditions, that must be added to UML diagrams ( "[ condition ]" ) .

(3) Inside each condition or case of the "alt",  there may be several messages among several objects, or to themselves, or none ( only the "return" arrow  ).

```
..........................................................
.......+---------+..............+---------+...............
.......|   Foo   |..............|   Bar   |...............
.......+----+----+..............+----+----+...............
............|........................|....................
..........+-+-+....................+-+-+..................
..........|   |......methodX().....|   |..................
..........|   +------------------->+   |..................
..........|   |....................|   |..DoSomething()...
..........|   |....................|   +---+..............
..........|   |....................|   |...|..............
..........|   |....................|   |...|..............
..........|   |....................|   |...|..............
..........|   |....................|   |<--+..............
..........|   |....................|   |..................
..+-----+-------------------------------------+...........
..|.alt.|.|   |....................|   |......|...........
..+-----+-------------------------------------+...........
..|.[option=1].....................|   |......|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   |......|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   +---+..|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   |...|..|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   |...|..|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   |...|..|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   |<--+..|...........
..|.......|   |<-------------------+   |......|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   |......|...........
..+-----+-------------------------------------+...........
..|.[option=2].....................|   |......|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   |......|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   |......|..// The wide bar its kept,
..|.......|   |<-------------------+   |......|..// even if there is a
..|.......|   |....................|   |......|..// previous return arrow
..+-------------------------------------------+...........
..|.[else]|...|....................|   |......|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   |......|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   |......|...........
..|.......|   |<-------------------+   |......|...........
..|.......|   |....................|   |......|...........
..+-------------------------------------------+...........
..........|   |....................|   |..................
..........+-+-+....................+-+-+..................
............|........................|....................
............|........................|....................
............X........................X....................
..........................................................
```

Cheers.

P.D. Any cheeseburguer or tuna-fishburguer for the cat ?

Comment: Your answer doesn't resolve my problem that how to draw more than one return lines from a method. The return line of doSomething() is only allowed to point to the class/object who calls it, in the example it's Bar, not Foo. Please try it in UML tool e.g. Astah.

Comment: @aleung: Please, check the update. The class wide bar is kept, even if there is a  "return arrow" before. If a "guard" is not true, its omitted, and ignored, as it didn't exist, and check the next "alt", and so on. Your chart, cuts the wide bar, at the first "guard".

Comment: I guess it's limitation of [Astah](http://astah.net/), it ends the bar at first return. Astah is my favor UML editor. I didn't try Visual paradigm for UML because it requires registration.